# Spring boot handling exception - Failed to write HTTP message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

i want to handle the error for the following controller method

```
@GetMapping(value= "search", params = {"id", "!name"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> getMovieById(@RequestParam(name = "id") short id) {
        Movie movie = this.movieService.getMovieById(id);
        if(null == movie) {
            throw new MovieNotFoundException("Unable to find moviee with id: " + id);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(movie);
    }
```

so if the id in the link nit found i'm throwing `MovieNotFoundException`.
but spring throw the following error:

```
Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Unable to find com.movies.mmdbapi.model.Movie with id 6; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unable to find com.movies.mmdbapi.model.Movie with id 6
```

Comment: Hi ! Please elaborate: what softwares are you using, to do what ? The more details you give, the easier it is to give an answer :)

Comment: What do you mean by softwares ? i'm using spring boot with spring data (repository jpa) and a rest controller .

Comment: @ScaryWombat it doesn't reach the condition, i put a system.out and doesn't shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use spring's out of the box `ControllerAdvice`. You don't need to handle your exceptions in Controller class. Just throw any Runtime Exception where-ever it occurs (e.g. Service Component or DAO).

Then write an Error Advice like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class MyErrorAdvice {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) //Response Code your want to return
    @ExceptionHandler({MovieNotFoundException.class})
    public void handleMovieNotFoundException(MovieNotFoundException e) {
        log.error("Exception : ", e);
        // Options lines 
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler({MyOtherException.class})
    public void handleMyOtherException(MyOtherException e) {
        log.error("Exception : ", e);
        // Options lines 
    }
}
```

That's it. Hope this helps.

Recently, I have drafted a post on [How to - Spring Boot Exceptions Handling](https://www.amitph.com/spring-rest-service-exception-handling/).

Answer (score 4):

Your **movie** object is sent through a **ResponseEntity** object as the **response**. And the **response** is going through **HTTP** as a **JSON** object.

So your **movie** object needs to **JSON stringify** it itself. **Java Reflection API** automatically does the job for you. It automatically calls **getters** in your **Movie** class and create the **JSON** object.

However some **getters** might not return the exact String representation of the relevant variable

**Ex:-**

```
public String getUserId() {
    return userId.toHexString();
}
```

In that case **HttpMessageNotWritableException** could occur.

So you can use **@JsonIgnore** annotation above the respective field to ignore it. Or return exact string representation through **getters**.

**Ex:-**

```
@JsonIgnore
private ObjectId userId;
```

Comment: Even though this answer is valid consider elaborating a little more to give the OP more insight.

Comment: Happy now? Cabrra ;)